# Want to plot correlation matrix with both control and stress data together

Tags: r

I have two data sets in my experiment with control and stress treatments, and i want to plot correlation matrix in a combined form having both values in a single plot along with the scatter plot and distribution graphs seen in this image[image: I want correlation plot like this]. Please provide the code for R software to plot a graph like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#Import your data

```
Head(Data)
```

#Load these libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
library(GGally)
```

#From column 1 to 13 should be your parameters, and the last column should be your group (i.e., the genotypes having 'Control' and 'Stress' treatments)

#Run this code

```
ggpairs(Data, 
    columns = 1:13, 
    aes(colour=Treatment),
    lower = list(continuous = "smooth"),
    upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor", 
                     method = "pearson")))
```